# How do I get all elements from a struct array, and add them into a string in c?

Tags: c, arrays, strcpy

```
char str[vector_total(&final_clause)];
    for(int i = 0; i<vector_total(&final_clause); i++)
    {
          printf("%s  ", (char*) vector_get(&final_clause,i)); // outputs b  a  -c  a  a  -c  -c
          strcpy(str, (char*) vector_get(&final_clause,i));
    } 
    printf("%s", str); //only prints -c (last )
    remove_repeatation(str); // removes repeats. Expected: b a-c
```

Evidently its replacing 'str' everyloop. So what is the best way to fix this? Not sure if this is a easy question but I just haven't been able to crack it using different approaches.

Comment: Please create a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`char str[vector_total(&final_clause)];` too small.

```
size_t len = vector_total(&final_clause);
char str[len*2 + 1]; // might be enough
```

> //only prints -c (last )

Code copies `vector_get()` into the same location so this is expected.

Perhaps use `strcat()` and `str[0] = 0;` for the first `strcat(str, ..` to work.

Comment: Thanks a bunch worked nicely. I wasn't sure at first what `str[0] = 0` did but it seemed to clean up some random characters at the beginning.

Comment: @thome.steve The first time `strcat(str, ...)` is called, `str` needs to be an empty string.  That is accomplished with `str[0] = 0;`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `strcat` instead of `strcpy`. `strcpy` replace the  content of `str` by the result of `vector_get()` when `strcat` concatenate `str` and `vector_get()`.

This should fix your problem:

```
char str[vector_total(&final_clause)];
char *result = NULL;
str[vector_total(&final_clause)] = '\0;
    for(int i = 0; i<vector_total(&final_clause); i++)
    {
          printf("%s  ", (char*) vector_get(&final_clause,i)); // outputs b  a  -c  a  a  -c  -c
          result = realloc(result, (sizeof(char) * strlen(vector_get(&final_clause,i));
          result = strcat(result, (char*) vector_get(&final_clause,i));
    } 
    printf("%s", str);
    remove_repeatation(str);
```

Comment: Need `char *result == NULL;` for later `realloc()` to work.  `realloc()` does not allocate for a null character - 1 too small.  First `strcat(str, ...` is a problem as `str` is not a _string_. (no \0).  Allocation lost with `result = strcat...`

Comment: Hi, thanks for the help. The first version seemed to okay and worked perfect with some of the adjustments chux - Reinstate Monica mentioned.`str[vector_total(&final_clause)] = NULL;`, I'm not sure about this lines function.

Comment: @thome.steve I ma de an error while typing this line, it's normally a '\0' to indicate the end of the string.